# Why the nav-tabs options didn't display in OpenCart?

Tags: php, opencart

Why nav-tabs options didn't display in OpenCart and also options of order_status also did not display even though there is a data in the database?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the error due multi-language problem. I see at least phrase `text_home` is missing.